# При запросе SQL через тело функции PHP получаю ошибку

Tags: javascript, php, sql

Мучаюсь с такой проблемой:
Мне нужно чтобы при клике по radio получить значение этого radio и передать его в SQL запрос. В JS я получаю значение.

```
$("input[name='select_account']").on('click', function () {
    var x = $("input[name='select_account']:checked").val();
})
```

Потом как я понимаю его надо передать в PHP и сделать запрос через SQL. Соответственно я делаю функцию, которая передают это значение, однако при получении запроса я получаю ошибку (Query failed). Однако если я запущу код запроса *вне тела функции*, то никакой ошибки не возникает.

```
function sql_query($user_id) {
    $query = 'select * from users WHERE id='.$user_id.';';
    $query_result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        if(!$query_result) {
            die('Query failed'.mysqli_error());
        } else {
            echo ('Complete');
        }
        return $query_result;
}
```

$connection я получаю ранее в коде без ошибок.

И вообще может я зря мучаюсь с этой функцией, может есть более простое решение?

Проблема решилась добавлением в функцию строки:

```
global $connection;
```

Спасибо всем за подсказки!

Comment: Если возникает какая либо ошибка, то следует указать её в вопросе

Comment: В данном коде в функции `sql_query()` `$connection` __не определен__

Comment: По возможности обратите внимание на [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php) и примеры функции [execute](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php), в частности на то, как передаются параметры в запрос, чтобы избежать SQL injection

Comment: используя ключевое слово `global`, вы не решаете проблему, а усугубляете её. Поверьте моему опыту, я такое проходил.